# MQL 4 ordersend error 138 only in testing not in live demo

Tags: mql4

I get ordersend error 138, be it buy or sell, but only in back testing not in live demo. I have try to adjust slippage to no avail. Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

```
double price = iClose(Symbol(), PERIOD_H1, 1);
   if (up > down && up > sideway){
      double stoploss = NormalizeDouble(price-piploss*Point, Digits);
      double takeprofit = NormalizeDouble(price+pipgain*Point, Digits);
      int ticket = OrderSend(Symbol(), OP_BUY, 1, price, 5, stoploss, takeprofit, "buy", 16384, 0, clrGreen);
      if (ticket<0){
         Print("Order send error: ", GetLastError());
      } else{
         Print("Order success");
      }
   } else if (down > up && down > sideway) {
      double stoploss = NormalizeDouble(price+piploss*Point, Digits);
      double takeprofit = NormalizeDouble(price-pipgain*Point, Digits);
      int ticket = OrderSend(Symbol(), OP_SELL, 1, price, 5, stoploss, takeprofit, "sell", 16384, 0, clrGreen);
      if (ticket<0){
         Print("Order send error: ", GetLastError());
      } else{
         Print("Order success");
      }
   } else {
      Print("sideway");
   }
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your price is close of the previous H1 candle. Probably you do open bar check before. Anyway, your computation may take time, that is why it is strongly recommended to `RefreshRates()` before sending the order. Next, you should use constants `Ask` and `Bid` when sending market orders, they are updated after refreshing rates. Otherwise you receive different errors (133, 136, 138).

Answer (score 0):

U try to open a Sell order by Ask  price or a Buy order by Bid price!

Open :

Buy order by --> Ask

&

Sell order by --> Bid.